# EC2 server losses internet connection and application fails to send email, sms and even yum updates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 5 EC2 servers in the same VPC and all of a sudden yesterday, all of my applications started failing to send email and sms. So I tried doing `git pull` of my project it also timed out. Then tried to install telnet using yum that to failed with Time out. I have checked almost everything including Network ACLs, Security Groups, Subnets, Iptables, etc and everything is correct. I am not sure why is this happening.
The weird thing is if I reboot the server once the internet comes for a brief amount of time and again it disconnects.

Attaching below are the errors I am facing:

[image]

[image]

```
Error while Generating the Tiny URL. Error: {"errno":-110,"code":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect","address":"XXX.XX.XXX.XX","port":443}


Error SendEmail UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `email.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the `ap-south-1' region.
```

Attaching screenshots of my Network ACLs, Security Groups, Subnets, and iptables:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please help with what am I doing wrong or if is this an issue with AWS EC2? My goal is to make sure my application works without timeout and git and yum starts working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try terminating and reprovisioning the instances, rather than rebooting them?  There may be some problem with the underlying hardware.  When you terminate and recreate an instance, it will likely end up in a different rack in the datacenter, which may solve the problem.

If the above helps, you should consider setting up an [application load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancer-getting-started.html) with an [auto scaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/auto-scaling-groups.html), with health checks enabled for both, so that the auto scaling group terminates unhealthy instances and replaces then with the new ones automatically.

You may also consider using [Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html) and stop worrying about underlying compute for e-mail and sms distribution altogether!

Comment: Hi Alex, I am already using SNS services. Also terminating and recreation a production EC2 server is not a viable solution in my case. As there is a lot of configuration made on the server and redoing is lot of efforts.

Comment: @JeetheshKotian if recreating your server is a lot of effort then you are using AWS wrong. At a minimum you should be able to quickly create an AMI from the server and then spin  up a new one from that. However, just stopping, and then restarting the server should be enough to boot it up on new underlying hardware. A reboot stays on the same hardware, but when you stop, and then restart, it should generally come up on new hardware.

Comment: I agree with @MarkB.  You should try and push all of your configuration into a Launch Template (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-launch-templates.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console).  The entire philosophy of the cloud is based on the idea of achieving resilience through automated deployment of many expendable cheap machines instead of a few very reliable but very expensive ones.

Comment: @AlexChadyuk thanks for your response. Aws had observed abnormal activities which resembled a DoS attacks, so to prevent that they Blocked HTTP/S Outbound Traffic and because of this, all this problem occurred. Your solution make sense but all the things in AWS were correct. Its because of this action by AWS we were facing this issue.